# Added validation constraints to inputs dynamically, but Angular not initialising them

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive, angular-validation

I have tried adding attributes such as `ng-required="true"` and `ng-pattern="/^(d)+$/"` dynamically as DOM is compiled by Angular. They are added and appear on the element when I inspect the element, however they do not appear to be initialised and do nothing.

I did this using the directive below, I pass the `inp` object into the directive scope from the template as it's compiled, the `inp` object contains all the data about how the input should be rendered.

```
.directive ('addConstraints', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope : {
          inp : '=inp'
        },
        link : function(scope, ele, attr)   {

                if(!scope.inp || !scope.inp.attributes) return;
                var attrs = scope.inp.attributes;

                for(var i = 0; i < attrs.length; i++) {
                ele.attr(attrs[i].attr, attrs[i].val);
            }

        }
}});
```

Use:

```
<div ng-controller="someController">

<div ng-repeat="inp in inputs">

<input ng-if="inp.type == 'text'" add-constraints inp="inp" type="text">

</div>

</div>
```

Using angularjs 1.5.8

Comment: I've no idea what you are trying to do. Post a reproducible example